# Dúvida na declaração entre expressão arrow e expressão de função de um evento

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Possuo o seguinte trecho de código:

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {"code here"});
```

Minha dúvida é... esse formato de escrita é igual a:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {"code here"});
```

E se não for, qual a diferença?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado @MagicHat. Ia fazer isso, porém tu já havia feito. kk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há diferênças na maneira de funcionar, para além do aspeto.

`() => {}` é uma função flecha (arrow function) e corre sempre no contexto que tiver sido chamada. Não aceita `.bind`, `.call`, `.apply` ou outras maneiras de impôr um contexto de execução.

No caso do teu código, um auscultador de evento, a diferênça é grande pois o `this` normalmente é o elemento que recebeu o `.addEventListener` e essa é a maneira de distinguir do `event.target` que é perdido com `event => {}`.

Repara neste exemplo ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzzwnudy/)):

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var info = document.querySelector('#info');

div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 info.innerHTML += ['legacy', this, e.target.tagName, '<br>'].join(' ');
});
div.addEventListener('click', e => {
 info.innerHTML += ['arrow', this, e.target.tagName, '<br>'].join(' ');
});
```

```html
<div>
    <button type="button">Clica-me!</button>
</div>
<p id="info"></p>
```

Nestes casos o `this` comporta-se de maneira bem diferente.

Answer (score 3):

*Arrow Function* pertence ao [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), possui uma sintaxe mais curta e vincula o valor *this* de maneira léxica.

> Uma expressão arrow function possui uma síntaxe mais curta quando
>   comparada com expressões de função (function expressions) e vincula o
>   valor de this de maneira léxica. Arrow functions sempre são anônimas.

Exemplo:

```
var a = [
  "Hidrogenio",
  "Helio",
  "Litio",
  "Berilio"
];

var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });

var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );
```

Nota para a ausência do *return* na segunda função.

Antes das *arrow functions* toda função definia seu próprio valor [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). Este comportamento é importuno com um estilo de programação orientado a objeto.

Nessa [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) é possível encontrar mais exemplos entre os dois tipos.